# Replace old file with new file

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a script to replace old files content with new files content which is appearing in the following format:

Old file : something.txt
New file : something.txt.new

Old file need to replaced with New file contents
New File name to be rename without new
Old file need to be deleted

Below script is not working :Could you please rewrite:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FOLDER_PATH=D:\test
for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set basename=test
    ren *.txt.new !basename!.txt
)
PAUSE
```

i have many files in folder and need to iterate through each file,only i need is basename variable need to be filled with the name of the old file name in each iteration

Comment: Removing the `bash` tag which is more relevant for development under `Linux`

Comment: your parameter sequence is wrong. See `ren /?`: `ren <source> <destination>`

Comment: can u rewrite this code i couldnt catch your syntax?

Comment: If you really are, as your code suggests, performing a file rename then this is all you need: `Ren "D:\test\*.txt" "*.txt.new"`.

Comment: its not like that ..i have many files in folder and need to iterate through each file,only i need is basename variable need to be filled with the name of the old file name in each iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set FOLDER_PATH=D:\test
for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%\*.new) do if "%%~ff" neq "%~f0" (
    ECHO move /Y "%%~ff" "%%~dpnf"
)
PAUSE
```

or

```
@echo off
setlocal
set FOLDER_PATH=D:\test
for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%\*.new) do if "%%~ff" neq "%~f0" (
    if exist "%%~dpnf" ECHO del "%%~dpnf"
    ECHO rename "%%~ff" "%%~nf"
)
PAUSE
```

Note that operational `move` (`del` and `rename`) commands are merely `ECHO`ed for debugging purposes.

Also note that `if "%%~ff" neq "%~f0"` could be omitted iterating `*.new` files as `%~f0` has an extension of `.bat` or `.cmd` (try `echo %~x0 %~f0`).

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~ff` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>`, `2>&1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. You missed a `\`in `%FOLDER_PATH%\*`.
2. You want to rename `*.new` files only, so why not using this pattern rather than `*`? If you are interested in files matching the pattern `*.txt.new`, then specify this instead of `*`.
3. There is no need for variable `basename`; simply use `%%~nf` to remove the (last) suffix (`.new`).
4. The `ren` command throws an error in case the target file already exists; since you want it to be overwritten, use `move /Y` instead. Add `> nul` to hide the summary `1 file(s) moved.`.
5. Remove the `if` query after having resolved item 2.

All in all, your script can be reduced to:

```cmd
@echo off
set "FOLDER_PATH=D:\test"
rem // Ensure to specify the correct pattern, `*.new` or `*.txt.new`:
for %%f in ("%FOLDER_PATH%\*.txt.new") do (
    > nul move /Y "%%~f" "%%~nf"
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid question Invalid answer

source 1

```
@echo off
set FOLDER_PATH=D:\test
cd /d "%FOLDER_PATH%"
ren "*.txt.new" "*.txt"
```

source 2

```
@echo off
set FOLDER_PATH=D:\test
cd /d "%FOLDER_PATH%"
ren "*.txt" "*.txt.new"
```

Comment: You should expand as to why this should be the correct answer, including what you have edited and what are you using.